# BackupPC -- PingPath and PingCmd

Tags: backuppc

BackupPC has two configuration variables:

```
$Conf{PingPath} = '/bin/ping';
Full path to the ping command.

$Conf{PingCmd} = '$pingPath -c 1 $host';
Ping command. The following variables are substituted at run-time:
  $pingPath      path to ping ($Conf{PingPath})
  $host          host name
```

I'm just trying to understand why there are two separate variables.  That is, what benefit does this setup provide as opposed to just a single variable

```
$Conf{PingCmd} = '/bin/ping -c 1 $host';
```

Comment: Wow, ask a question and get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like an improvement iteration where somebody ran into portability issues with `ping` either not installed in the default `$PATH`  or not in `/bin/` and then deciding to make the absolute path to `ping`  a configurable parameter, which would only need updating in one place.

Creating a new parameter when that parameter will be referenced only once, that may seem a bit redundant, but maybe that wasn't known beforehand or it is simply a (personal) coding style preference.
Since parameter expansion/substitution is cheap doing that is not harmful.